# Pandas local HTML erros

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas

[Download File](https://grupomdmoldes-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/ruidinis_mdgroup-global_com/EUTY-lE1q05Lgr1xU90ofSMBx5uJY5zbilDUwxINWPATEw?e=I2SSeg)Hi| I am trying to read local html files with pandas and one field is not passing the numeric value but a string that is not shown but it is inside the html code. How can I read the table with the values shown in the html ?

In the picture below you can see that I should be getting the 00:21.44 value but instead I am getting the string

`"document.Write(Timefactor("0:19:46","raster"))`

Any help ?
I am attaching the file.

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a minimal working example inside of stackoverflow? What steps have you tried? Besides, it is rather sketchy to download a file from the internet

Comment: Hi! And thanks for your response. I used pandas to read it, pd.read_html but I get the code instead of the right value because inside the html file it has two values. I know it is danger to download a file from the internet but I am a member here I would not risk get kick out of here over a bad file.

Comment: Hi, see this [meta most](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386997/how-can-i-upload-a-file-to-stack-overflow)

Comment: There is something you may want to check. When you open the page in firefox, the javascript is executed and transform 0:19:46 to 00:21:44.
pd.read_html downloads the webpage without executing the javascript code, so the value remains 0:19:46.
Try downloading using requests module and verify the html content? (`import requests; requests.get(url).content`)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Hi again. (import requests; requests.get(url).content) won´t read files saved on your hardrive. Or I dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are reading raw HTML, but the browser also renders Javascript that it contains. You need to render HTML the same way the browser does.

For that you will need to install `requests_html` and `html5lib` packages. Now load and render your HTML. Then you can proceed as usual.

```
import pandas as pd
from requests_html import HTML
with open( << your file here >>, 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as fi:
    html_orig = fi.read()
    
html_rendered = HTML(html=html_orig)
html_rendered.render()
df = pd.read_html(html_rendered.html)
```

I would also suggest to clean the rendered HTML a little before feeding to `pandas`, for example:

```
import re
last_table = html_rendered.find('table')[-1].html
last_table_noscript = re.sub(r'<script[^<]*.+?<\/script>','', last_table, flags=re.MULTILINE)
df2 = pd.read_html(last_table_noscript)
df2

[   ASS.     Programa    T    Ferramenta  ÃƒÆ’Ã‹Å“  RC  ID Cone  H Total  H RESP.   ZMin   ap/ae STK(xy/z) ComentÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¡rio     F   RPM     Tempo        WKPL  Notas
 0   NaN  5414TR20112    2  TR32R1.6 des        32  16  M16L100       37      NaN  12793  0,2/17     0,15/   Desbaste Raster  3500  1800  00:09:46  (3+2) 2POS    NaN
 1   NaN  5414TR20113    3        TR35R1        35   1  M16L100       34      NaN   -957  0,2/16        0/   Desbaste Raster  2000  2500  00:03:50  (3+2) 2POS    NaN
 2   NaN  5414TR20114    3        TR35R1        35   1  M16L100       34      NaN  12591  0,2/17        0/   Desbaste Raster  2000  2500  00:01:36  (3+2) 2POS    NaN
 3   NaN  5414TR20115    2  TR32R1.6 des        32  16  M16L100       37      NaN  -1865    0,2/        0/       Z Constante  3500  1800  00:34:55  (3+2) 2POS    NaN
 4   NaN  5414TR20116  160  EHHB-4120-Ap        12   6  CT12L75       60     36.0    505    /0,3        0/            Raster  3500  6200  00:21:44  (3+2) 2POS    NaN]
```